# how to know if the user input comes from the speech-to-text function

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, speech-to-text, onkeydown

I have a class derived from `EditText` where I need to know whether the input from the user comes from the soft keyboard or from the speech-to-text function (which is activated with the microphone key on the soft keyboard).

For that purpose I override `onKeyDown()` , hoping to set up a flag whenever a key is pressed, and that way indicate that the input is coming from the keyboard and not from the speech-to-text function.

My `onKeyDown()` override detects keyCode `KEYCODE_ENTER` when pressing on the "Done" key on the soft keyboard, as expected. However, pressing any other keys on the soft keyboard do not fire onKeyDown and therefore I cannot set the flag I want.

I have seen many posts on the Internet about the onKeyDown function, but all are concered with trapping the "Done" key and there is no information about trapping the other keys on the soft keyboard.

Any ideas will be appreciated.